# How to TRUNCATE table with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

How I can truncate a table with c#.

I do this but it doesn't work.

```
cmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE dalbara;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Visual Studio give me this error:

> Invalid SQL command, you only can do 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE',
>   'SELECT' or 'UPDATE'

I want to delete and restart all of my access table. With the DELETE command, the autoincrement values, doesn't reset.

Comment: It is a permission issue. The user your code is running through does not have permission in the Db to TRUNCATE.

Comment: How I can activate this permission?

Comment: Determine the user account used in the db connection and in the db give that user ALTER TABLE permission on the table you are attempting to TRUNCATE. If you are using integrated WIndows Security, it is the user running the code that needs that permission on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're some sort of database context you can do this:

```
dbContext.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE <tableName>");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Server=localhost;Database=dbase;Uid=root;password=;)    
string query = "TRUNCATE TABLE " + yourTableName
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Use this code to truncate table

Comment: Says that I require an open connection when I try to run this, tells me that my connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL
Go -> Home ->Users menu-> select User in table ->Edit Privileges->Check All Global privileges -> Go

Now execute truncate code.

Answer (score 0):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * FROM  'root'@'localhost';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO  'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
```

Change your host name and username, execute in your server and run your truncate c# code.